# Redshift failing on column named "MM"

Tags: amazon-redshift

I get this error on a column named `mm` in Redshift:

```
select sum(mm) mm from foo;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "mm"
LINE 1: select sum(mm) mm from foo;
                       ^
```

I do not get the same error if I alias the column to something else like `select sum(mm) mm2 ...`

what's special about `mm`?  It is not on the list of reserved words.

Comment: interesting - suggest you email AWS support with this one - and please report back on response?

Comment: I can duplicate the issue, might be a bug.

Comment: Contacted support and ticket filed.  Will let you know when I get a response

Comment: interestingly full and valid query `select 1 mm` also fails but i.e. `select 1 m` works

Answer (score 0):

Use `AS`:

```
SELECT
  sum(mm) AS mm
FROM foo
```